# SVG inline with Logo Text

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, svg

I'm having trouble to align a text with an SVG logo inside a mdbootstrap navbar. I already tried all the solutions in this thread [position svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639613/how-do-i-position-my-svg-inline-with-text) but none is working. I'm just learning SVG and I'm not an expert using CSS.

With the current CSS settings I'm displaying the logo in the middle of the navbar but I need it to be just before the text.

html navbar

```
<!--Main Navigation-->
<header>

    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark light-blue scrolling-navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <svg id="eerc-logo-strokes" viewBox="0 0 322 260" style="background-color:#ffffff00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="322px" height="260px">
                <g>
                    <path d="M 191.1762 129.8679 C 190.8577 120.7468 198.0377 113.0452 207.1588 112.7267 C 216.2799 112.4082 223.9796 119.5901 224.2981 128.7113 C 224.6166 137.8323 217.4366 145.532 208.3155 145.8505 C 199.1944 146.169 191.4948 138.989 191.1762 129.8679 Z" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
                    <path d="M 22.7103 103.2846 L 42.6281 77.7907 L 74.6689 82.2927 L 83.0325 102.9983 L 180.9312 116.757 C 186.3008 105.3062 198.7038 98.1359 211.8558 99.9855 C 214.3942 100.3427 216.8107 101.0149 219.0764 101.9583 L 244.0526 69.9884 L 235.3467 48.4384 L 255.2645 22.9445 L 287.3033 27.4466 L 299.4246 57.4445 L 279.505 82.9405 L 256.49 79.7049 L 231.4968 111.6949 C 235.9615 117.7191 238.1623 125.4255 237.0412 133.4082 C 235.92 141.3889 231.6785 148.1902 225.7281 152.752 L 236.2058 178.684 L 259.2207 181.9195 L 271.34 211.9175 L 251.4222 237.4114 L 219.3832 232.9094 L 207.264 202.9114 L 221.5711 184.595 L 211.1041 158.6899 C 208.6681 158.9705 206.157 158.9507 203.6187 158.5936 C 190.4686 156.7458 180.5208 146.434 178.5148 133.9485 L 80.6161 120.1897 L 66.8685 137.7866 L 34.8295 133.2826 L 22.7103 103.2846 L 22.7103 103.2846 Z" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
                </g>
            </svg>

            <svg id="eerc-logo-fill-wnw" viewBox="0 0 322 260" style="background-color:#ffffff00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="322px" height="260px">
                <path d="M 22.7103 103.2846 L 22.725 103.325 L 54.7493 107.7886 L 74.705 82.385 L 74.6689 82.2927 L 42.6281 77.7907 L 22.7103 103.2846 Z" fill="#fff" />
            </svg>

            <svg id="eerc-logo-fill-ene" viewBox="0 0 322 260" style="background-color:#ffffff00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="322px" height="260px">
                <path d="M 279.72 82.67 L 299.4246 57.4445 L 287.4 27.685 L 267.3857 52.9424 L 279.72 82.67 Z" fill="#fff" />
            </svg>

            <svg id="eerc-logo-fill-sse" viewBox="0 0 322 260" style="background-color:#ffffff00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0" y="0" width="322px" height="260px">
                <path d="M 207.264 202.9114 L 219.3832 232.9094 L 251.1 237.365 L 239.301 207.4135 L 207.264 202.9114 Z" fill="#fff" />
            </svg>
            <strong>
                DATUS</strong></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" (click)="mobile.toggle()" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- Collapsible content -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [mdbCollapse]="isCollapsed" #mobile="bs-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        </div>
        <!-- Collapsible content -->
    </nav>

</header>
<!--Main Navigation-->
```

css

```
body {
    background: #fff;
  }

  #log {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 40px;
    //bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    color: #393;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #log p {
    margin: 0;
  }

  svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  svg#eerc-logo-fill-wnw, // West-northwest rectangle
  svg#eerc-logo-fill-ene, // East-northeast rectangle
  svg#eerc-logo-fill-sse { // South-southeast rectangle
    display: none;
  }
```

It's for an Angular2+ app so I have a typescript file where I use a bit of JQuery. Here is the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery:any;
declare var $:any;
declare var drawsvg: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.scss']
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  var $svgFillWnw = $('svg#eerc-logo-fill-wnw'); // West-northwest rectangle
  var $svgFillEne = $('svg#eerc-logo-fill-ene'); // East-northeast rectangle
  var $svgFillSse = $('svg#eerc-logo-fill-sse'); // South-southeast rectangle

  function animate() {
    $svgFillWnw.hide();
    $svgFillEne.hide();
    $svgFillSse.hide();
    $svgFillWnw.fadeIn(400, function() {
      $svgFillEne.fadeIn(300, function() {
        $svgFillSse.fadeIn(200);
      });
    });
  }

  animate();

  }

}
```

So, how can I put the SVG inline with the logo text? Thanks for your help as always!

Answer (score 0):

make height and width of svg 100% as it is right now static and 260px / 322px

Comment: hey cyrus, thanks for your reply but its not working either

Comment: i can see your code its still have the height in css i was saying you to give svg a height and width 100% and set its height with parent div